# Excel: look up for numeric values in ascending order, in cells that has duplicated values

Tags: database, excel, function, indexing, duplicates

almost new year. I've got an Excel question I already said.

In worksheet "Workouts", I have a "WorkoutsSummary" table, containing the following information:

[image: Excel table]

As you can see, there are two cells containing the workout "Ares" (that's just a name for the training session), however, in the table column header "Workout Order" (second column), they have different values. In the table I can add more rows that can contain the same values (same Workout, same Start Time, same End Time, same Workout Duration), **except** in the Workout Order column (is unique for each row).

So, having said that, what I want to do is to show all Ares workouts (that means showing the Workout Duration value), in other worksheet named "Results", in ascending order. Now, as I said, it's in ascending order, and even though Ares is repeated twice, the numeric value in Workout Order isn't. This means that in the Results worksheet it should first be displayed the first Ares (containing the Workout Duration of 16:03), and below it the second Ares (containing the Workout Duration of 20:04).

I created this code:

```
=INDEX(WorkoutsSummary[Workout Duration], MATCH("Ares", WorkoutsSummary[Workout], 0))
```

This code, used in cell C13 in the worksheet Results, displays "16:03", which is the workout duration of the first Ares. **THE PROBLEM** is I can't figure out how I can use another code to display the second Ares. Obviously I can't use the same code because I'll always show the duration of the same first Ares. That's when I think the Workout Order values comes in play.

Any unclear thing, comment and I'll try to explain better.

Comment: You can use a pivot table for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `small(if())`:

```
 =INDEX(WorkoutsSummary[Workout Duration], MATCH(SMALL(IF( "Ares" = WorkoutsSummary[Workout],WorkoutsSummary[Workout Order]),1),IF( "Ares" = WorkoutsSummary[Workout],WorkoutsSummary[Workout Order]), 0))
```

This is an array and needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Change the 1 in the second argument of the small to 2 to get the second and so forth.

You could use `Count()` or some other function to dynamically count, but this will give you some place to start.